# How to add a value to a position in a range to cycle over but skipping a sub range?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm making a generative art program that at some points it requires to pick a color at random, near the red ones. There are several approaches I could take, but the one I've been trying baffles me (and now I just want to understand what I'm failing at)

If we had a range ([0;360] in this case) and some position within said range, how could we add a value to that position and skip a sub-range, like [30;330]? I can't find a way to properly do it – being at 350 and adding 360 should not output 350, since for every 360 there's a range between to skip several times (e.g.: it would make a leap from 29 to 330 if 1 was added from there)

Edit: What I've tried to do exactly is having a main range set between 0 and a float variable, and another one by another two floats:

```java
    static float range = 360;
    static float position = 25; // the current pos within [0;360]
    static float skipFrom = 30; // skip from here
    static float skipTo = 330; // to here
```

This would mean the given range is [0;360]. If we were at `position = 23` and added 2, the new position should be `330`. So I would kind of think of it as `position = add(position, 2);` outputting `330`

Now, if `position == 355` and we added `5`, it should return `0`.

But if we added `30` instead (being `position` equal to `335`), it should return `330`. It was my intention to make it cycle over as many times as necessary (so we could pass values much larger than the main range, like a thousand).

This is what I tried the most:

```java
public class main {
    static float rangeEnd = 360;
    static float position = 25;
    static float skipFrom = 30;
    static float skipTo = 330;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Before " + position);
        position += moveHue(6);
        System.out.println("Now " + position);
    }

    public static float moveHue(float displacement) {
          if (displacement >= rangeEnd) {
            displacement = moveHue(displacement - rangeEnd);
          }
          else if (displacement > skipFrom && displacement < skipTo) {
            displacement = moveHue(skipTo - skipFrom + displacement);
          }
          return displacement;
    }
}
```

Now of course I wasn't taking several things into consideration (or couldn't grasp how to do implement them). My intention was to make a function to discard the excess in every cycle, and add the actual number later (which I guess it could have worked if I had taken the difference between ranges somewhere?)

Amongalen's approach seems to work perfectly - I'll adapt it to what I need :^)

Comment: I did not understand your problem, could you edit your question and try to reexplain it ?

Comment: I think you might be mistaken about adding 360 to 350 not resulting in 350. You have 0-29 and 331-360. Which is 60 numbers. So if you add 60, you should be back at 350. Adding 360 is just doing that 6 times. You will still be at 350. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work more or less. There may be some off-by-one errors so you need to test it with more values.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  static int skipStart = 30;
  static int skipEnd = 330;
  static int rangeEnd = 360;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(add(20,5));
    System.out.println(add(20,15));
    System.out.println(add(20,25));
    System.out.println(add(20,35));
    System.out.println(add(20,45));
    System.out.println(add(20,55));
    System.out.println(add(20,65));
    System.out.println(add(20,75));
    System.out.println(add(20,85));
    System.out.println(add(20,95));
    System.out.println(add(20,105));
  }

  public static int add(int curr, int move){

    int movableRange = rangeEnd - (skipEnd-skipStart);
    int result = curr + (move % movableRange);
    result %= rangeEnd;
    if(result>skipStart && result<skipEnd){
        result += (skipEnd-skipStart);
    }
    result %= rangeEnd;
    return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: if my curr is 355 (for example) and my move 50, movableRange = 60, result = 405. if will not be fulfilled. result % rangeEnd = 405 % 360 = 45. Right inside the range that should be skipped. It's a great answer though, just have to fix that little problem ;)

Comment: @Mark thanks for pointing that out, it should be fixed now. Not sure if thats the cleanest solution but seems to work for me.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense that everything I was trying, so it seems great to me.

Answer (score -1):

Define an array with the valid values in it and we will keep the index of the value . For the example you gave suppose [30,330] and [0,9] are invalid so our `values` array will contain [10,29] and [331,360], set the `index` to 19 and `values[index]` will be 29. then by adding one to the `index` you get `value[index]` equals to 331. This is acceptable if ranges are not that long and you are not doing the operation with so many different set of ranges.